# Fastest way to search a user

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to make a user search mechanism in PHP using a MySQL database. I have two columns in the user table - `username` and `fullname`. I want to search through both columns and sort the result by relevance. Assuming the database is huge, what is the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: This will largely depend on what indexes you're using on your database and what field types you're using. (I'd recommend updating your question with the relevant table schema.) That said "relevance" may be a stretch depending on your requirements.

Comment: Please show some example data.

Comment: It largely depends on what you mean by "relevance".  Can you elaborate on what you are expecting as results?

Answer (score 1):

I can advice you to think about:

1. [indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) your table
2. saving as short data per row as you can (Smaller indices and smaller
   constant-size data types are faster)